# How to reset the custom control

Tags: .net, xamarin

I am using CollectionView to display items from the MainSection class.

Behaviour: I click on the custom control "selectedSection" and it redirects me to the next page. Then I press the back button and try to click on the same control one more time. It doesn't redirect me the second time until I chose the other control.

Goal: to make click on the same control redirect me to next page.

Thanks in advance.

XML:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="optionsList"
                            Margin="0,30,0,0"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}"
                            SelectionMode="Single" 
                            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSection}"
                            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" 
                            SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                 VerticalItemSpacing="20"
                                 HorizontalItemSpacing="20" Span="2"/>
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding SectionName}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            FontFamily="LightFont"
                            FontSize="15"
                            TextColor="Black"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.Footer>
                <Grid HeightRequest="0"/>
            </CollectionView.Footer>
</CollectionView>
```

Page ViewModel

```
private MainSection selectedSection;
        public MainSection SelectedSection
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedSection;
            }
            set
            {
                selectedSection = value;
            }
        }

        public Command SelectionCommand => new Command(DisplaySection);

        private void DisplaySection()
        {
            if(selectedSection != null)
            {
                
                var viewModel = new GeneralInfoViewModel();
                var sectionPage = new GeneralInfoPage { BindingContext = viewModel };
                //selectedSection = null;              changing it back to null doesn't work

                var navigation = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
                navigation.PushAsync(sectionPage, true);
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you using a ListView?  There is not enough context here to determine what you are actually doing.

Comment: Just added the details, will this do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `SelectionChangedCommand` only fires when the selection **changes**

```
SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}"
```

this means that if you select the same item twice, the command will not fire

you can work around this by setting the `SelectedItem = null`

your code attempts to do this

```
selectedSection = null;  // changing it back to null doesn't work
```

but this does not work because `selectedSection` is the **backing store** for your property, not the public property itself, and your class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.   You can either fix those two problems, or just do

```
optionsList.SelectedItem = null;
```

Comment: Roger that. Could you please give some advises on INotifyPropertyChanged implementation here? I am not sure how to implement it right.

Comment: there are hundreds, possibly thousands, of existing questions, tutorials, samples, videos and posts about using INPC